# combine image and solidcolor background for a WPF Form

Tags: wpf, background

I have a WPF form that I am building.  I want to specify a background image for the window, which is easy enough.  However, I also want to specify a color so that the area of the form not covered by the image is white.  I've seen some examples that show using two different background brushes, but when I try that VS.NET tells me I can't have multiple brushes.

This is the XAML I'm using

```
<Window x:Class="Consent.Client.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF"
    Title="Shell" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" FontSize="24">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top"  Stretch="None" TileMode="None" ImageSource="logo_header2.png" />
    </Window.Background>
    <ItemsControl Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" >
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

This works great for the image, but the background not covered by the image is black.  How do I make it white?  Changing the image itself is not really an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (I removed everything not directly relevant to the question to make the code clearer):

```
<Window x:Class="Consent.Client.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Background="White">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="logo_header2.png" />
      </Grid.Background>
      <ItemsControl>
      </ItemsControl>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Basically, set the window's background to the behind the image color, than put a grid in the window and give the grid you background image, put everything inside the grid instead of directly in the window.

Answer (score 4):

As an Extension to [Nirs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/515650/5006592) answer. If you want to have margins around your content, but let the background image be able to fill the whole window, you can also stack backgrounds using borders:

```
<Window x:Class="Consent.Client.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Background="White">

    <Border Padding="10">
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="logo_header2.png" />
        </Border.Background>
     <!--<Your content >-->
    </Border>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can combine brushes. You could play around with ImageBrush, or you could forget the "background" and stack the items on top of each other in a Grid:

```
<Window x:Class="Consent.Client.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF"
    Title="Shell" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" FontSize="24">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="logo_header2.png" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ItemsControl Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" >
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```